# How can I see the java local variables value on the fly when thread blocked

Tags: java, variables, local

I can use Btrace to see method parameters when the method called. but how can I see the variables when the thread are blocked or sleeping. 
As I know, the dump file generated by jmap can only show global variables.

Comment: If the code in that thread is well-written, it should handle interrupt()ing out of the wait cleanly - so I would set my debugger to stop on InterruptedException, then grab the thread you're interested in and call interrupt() on it - something you may be able to do on your IDE, but I confess I never tried...

Comment: I think this is possible to do in some debuggers by selecting the thread as a context, and then examining its stack trace.  You'll have to check out the details for your debugger/IDE, but I think NetBeans can do this.

Comment: I mentioned in production environment not developing. so IDE can not be used.